# quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.bind-parameters - don't work

Tags: hibernate, logging, quarkus

I migrated from Quarkus version `1.10.5.Final` to `1.13.3.Final` and the `quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.bind-parameters=true` property stopped working.

When the application starts I receive the following warning:

```
WARN  [io.qua.run.log.LoggingSetupRecorder] (Quarkus Main Thread) Log level TRACE for category 'org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder' set below minimum logging level DEBUG, promoting it to DEBUG
```

Until version `1.10.5.Final` this worked fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the [Quarkus logging guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging) I've found that I must change the `quarkus.log.min-level` property:

[image]

So I just changed to TRACE and everything worked fine:

```
quarkus.log.min-level=TRACE
quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.bind-parameters=true
```

Comment: I opened one issue about this in the Quarkus project: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/16885